# Python.Net: Do I need "using (Py.GIL())" in a callback from .Net to Python?

Tags: python, .net, python.net

The Python.Net page https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet says:

> "All calls to python should be inside a using (Py.GIL()) {/* Your code here */} block."

I have a Python application that calls into a .Net dll. The .Net dll starts a new thread which does some work and then calls back into Python.
If I wrap the callback in a "using (Py.GIL())" then my code prints the following error when the Python main thread completes:

```
Fatal Python error: auto-releasing thread-state, but no thread-state for this thread
Python runtime state: finalizing (tstate=00890970)
```

My code deliberately has the callback still being processed by function python_callback when the main Python thread finishes. I want everything to stop cleanly when the main Python thread finishes.

If I DON'T wrap the callback in a "using (Py.GIL())" then it works fine. So my question is:

**Does the callback from .Net to Python need to be wrapped in "using (Py.GIL())" ?**

If yes: how do I avoid this error message?

Python code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference(r"C:\MyDotNet\MyDotNet.dll")
import System
from MyDotNet import MyDotNetClass

def main():
    print(datetime.now(), 'Python started')
    dot_net_obj = MyDotNetClass(System.Action[System.Object](python_callback))
    time.sleep(10)
    print(datetime.now(), 'Python main thread finished')

def python_callback(arg):
    print(datetime.now(), 'Python: In callback, arg =', arg)
    time.sleep(20)    # <-- to keep the callback running when the main thread finishes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

.Net code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Python.Runtime;

namespace MyDotNet
{
    public class MyDotNetClass
    {
        public MyDotNetClass(Delegate callback)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                using (Py.GIL())    // <--- Is it safe to remove this 'using (Py.GIL())'?
                {
                    object[] paramToPass = new object[1];
                    paramToPass[0] = "The C# work is done";
                    callback.DynamicInvoke(paramToPass);
                }
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
2020-11-23 10:10:30.168585 Python started
2020-11-23 10:10:33.191054 Python: In callback, arg = The C# work is done
2020-11-23 10:10:40.191273 Python main thread finished
Fatal Python error: auto-releasing thread-state, but no thread-state for this thread
Python runtime state: finalizing (tstate=00890970)
```

Using Python 3.8, Python.Net 2.5.1, .Net Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if threading is involved. [See an issue in Python.NET repo](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/795)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, if I keep the "using (Py.GIL())" wrapper it prints the error "Fatal Python error: auto-releasing thread-state, but no thread-state for this thread" when the main Python thread finishes. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to ensure all other threads that ever run Python code are stopped before you try to shut the main thread down.

Comment: My Python application provides an API for user Python scripts so I have no warning when the main thread terminates. The callbacks from .Net into Python can happen at any time.

When a thread is passed from .Net to Python I can see that it is a daemon thread. My understanding is that in when the main Python thread terminates it will automatically terminate all daemon threads. This is what I want - I don't mind that they are terminated immediately. Why can't Python.Net silently allow the other threads to stop when the main thread completes?

Comment: I found a workaround: In python_callback, if I start a new daemon thread to do the work then the error does not get printed.

The Python.Net behaviour still seems wrong because it is inconsistent depending which daemon thread is busy when the main thread completes:
- Created in .Net then passed to Python: Get 'Fatal Python error'
- Created in .Net, passed to Python which starts new Python thread: No error