# How do I tell if a python script has finished before calling Py.GIL from C# via pythonnet

Tags: c#, multithreading, python.net

I have a C# program that starts a long running python program on a separate (C#) thread. It does this via "await Task.Run(() => cntl.doTest());".

```
public void doTest()
        {
            PythonEngine.Initialize();
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                test = Py.Import("tester");  //ok
                test.TestLoop.loop(); //ok
            }
        }
```

The main thread has a timer that periodically calls a function to get a python variable:

```
public int getCntr()
        {        
            using (Py.GIL()) 
            {
                int foo = test.TestLoop.cntr; //ok
                test.TestLoop.stopLoop = true; //ok -- causes python to exit normally
                return foo; //first time through, ok; never gets past "using" on second try
            }        
        }
```

Once called, the function stops the python program by setting python variable "test.TestLoop.stopLoop".

Everything works continuously if I comment out the "stopLoop=true".

If include that statement, the first call works fine, but when I call "getCntr" the second time the "using (Py.GIL())" statement hangs the C# program (i.e. in VS-debugger, the thread appears to be executing but does not move past the "using GIL" statement). I suspect this is because the python program has already exited normally (via setting the "stopLoop" in python).

So, is there a test I should do before executing the "using GIL()" statement to determine if the python program has exited? I looked into testing something on Python.Runtime and on PythonEngine, but did not see what to do.

I thought the problem might be because the "PythonEngine.Initialize" was on a thread that had ended before the second call to "getCntr". However I cannot initialize the engine outside of the doTest thread (because then the "using Py.GIL" block is skipped over in doTest and the "import" is never executed).

This problem might be similar to [Python.Net: Do I need "using (Py.GIL())" in a callback from .Net to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967321/python-net-do-i-need-using-py-gil-in-a-callback-from-net-to-python).

I consulted *http://pythonnet.github.io/ and https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Threading
but found no answer.

This is my solution which works, but seems cumbersome:

1. Add a variable (string aLock = "";) that will indicate when the doTest thread has finished.
2. Set this variable to "done" when the doTest thread has returned (i.e. after the "await Task.Run()" statement).
3. Test this variable (aLock !="done") before the "using GIL" block in getCntr.
4. Lock aLock before reading and setting.

Answer (score 1):

Please, see https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/16f04e9c0281cd1e4c266399b35ee89069eb36fe/src/embed_tests/TestInterrupt.cs

**TL;DR;** You should call `PythonEngine.Initialize()` followed by `PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads()` in your app main thread. This will solve "because then the `using Py.GIL` block is skipped over".

Actually, in your scenario with `PythonEngine.Initialize` outside of `doTest` you should have seen `Py.GIL` hang in `doTest` because GIL is being held by the thread, that called `PythonEngine.Initialize`.

The reason for all above is very simple: when a thread calls `PythonEngine.Initialize()`, it has GIL lock when call completes. My guess is it behaves this way for convenience of writing single-threaded programs. `BeginAllowThreads` explicitly releases GIL so that other threads could run Python code. When you do this, **main thread must also use `Py.GIL`**.

**UPD** I just noticed, that Threading page you linked actually [mentions that](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Threading#what-to-do-when-calling-python-from-c).